# MLE for choosing models

Tags: maximum-likelihood, model-selection

let say I have 2 models with the same number of parameters.
I implemented the Gaussian Log-Likelihood in R, based on real data for both models.
In the end, one model provides a higher MLE than the other one.
I conclude that the model with the highest MLE better fits with data and so is more relaible.
Is this intuition correct?
Thanks

Comment: You really need to tell us more, such as if the models are nested. In that case, the most general model (that with more parameters) will always have highest likelihood at the maximum  ... so your method is not a good way of selection. Look into AIC or other information criteria, or cross validation, or at least tell us (much) more!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Is there a way for nested models to have the same number of parameters?

Comment: @Dave: I didn't see that restriction ... I guess then they would be reparametrizations of each other! so, in this case, comparing AIC reduces to comparing max likelihoods

Comment: Hi: yes. If the larger model  that is containing the nested model has coefficients that are statistically zero, then it is possible that the larger model could have the same number of coefficients statistically. So, if you have a nested model, you can test whether the larger model variables that are not  in the nested model and see if they are statistically different from zero.

Comment: The models are the same despite of the fact that the error term (which is a white noise) in one model is multiplied by the lagged dependent variable: $y_{t-1}$*$\epsilon$

Answer (score 2):

Since your two models has the same number of parameters, comparing them by max likelihood will give the same result as comparing them with AIC (or other information criteria such as BIC). We can assume the two models are  not nested, otherwise they would be equal (or reparametrizations).

So if it is problematic to compare them by likelihood, the same problems would occur comparing by AIC. And there are indeed some problems, and also controversies. [There are many posts here discussing this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=aic+non-nested+answers%3A1), so have a look there!

But, in many cases should be OK. What to look out for:

- The models should be for **the same data, represented in the same way**. So one model for $Y$, another for $\log Y$ is not comparable this way.
- If the likelihood functions are not of the same form, they must not be simplified by leaving out "irrelevant" constants! (R, for instance, often leave out constants ...)
- If one model is discrete, and the other a continuous approximation, likelihoods can not be compared.